# laravel passport + scopes token is invalid because its size is too big

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have problem in **scopes** =>

> the browser show me this error when i try login :
>
> `Cookie “token” is invalid because its size is too big. Max size is 4096 B.`

And when i search for problem i realise that :

When you make a new scope and attach it to user , **your token will be more bigger**

I using alot of scops ( scopes for **every action** in app )

---

#### AuthServiceProvider.php

```php
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies
        = [
            'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        if ( ! $this->app->routesAreCached() ) {
            Passport::routes();
        }


        $scope_controller = new ScopeController();
        $scopes           = $scope_controller->get();

        Passport::tokensCan( $scopes );

    }
}
```

#### ScopeController.php

```php
class ScopeController extends Controller
{
    public function get(): array
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('permission_scopes')) {
            $scopes = PermissionScope::all()->toArray();
            $scopes_array = [];
            foreach ($scopes as $key => $scope) {
                $scopes_array[$scope['value']] = $scope['description'];
            }
            return $scopes_array;
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

#### permission_scopes table

[image]

#### Login method

```php
 public function generateToken(User $user, string $name = 'default_token'): object
    {
        $scopes = $this->getScopes($user); // this methode gets scopes
        $obj_token = $user->createToken($name, $scopes); // and this one generate the token 
        $access_token = $obj_token->accessToken; // token is ready here  ** but its to BIG **
        $expiration = $obj_token->token->expires_at;
        return (object)['token' => $access_token, 'expiration' => $expiration];
    }
```

> where is my problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: should i make scopes for every action in app ?